# ReCaptcha: How to autosubmit the form when the captcha was send

Tags: javascript, forms, recaptcha

I want to use ReCaptcha to load some extra data on the page. I want the form to be auto submitted when the ReCaptcha was entered. So that I don't need the extra submit button. The problem is that recaptcha loads its content inside an iframe, so its a bit difficult.

At the moment I have this form:

```
<form action="javascript:getInfo(grecaptcha.getResponse(widget1));" >
      <div id="captcha"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How do I get something like an Event-Listener on the recaptcha submit which submits the outer form?

Comment: What version of recaptcha are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's sounds like an interesting technique. It would cut down on the clicking and key strokes for the user. Here is how you could do that, by listening for the successful captcha response you would be able to follow up with the desired action. Here is an example and some documentation. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#example

```js
var RC2KEY = 'sitekey';

function reCaptchaVerify(response) {
  if (response === document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha-response').value) {
    document.forms['form-name'].submit();
  }
}

function reCaptchaExpired() {
  /* do something when it expires */
}

function reCaptchaCallback() {
  grecaptcha.render('id', {
    'sitekey': RC2KEY,
    'callback': reCaptchaVerify,
    'expired-callback': reCaptchaExpired
  });
}
```

```html
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=reCaptchaCallback&render=explicit'></script>
```

Comment: The code snippet no longer works. Could you please update it, I am now stumbling on this non-working answer.

Comment: I would love to help. Exactly what problem are you having?

Comment: Works fine for me.  My form action is set to `action="?"` and not what the poster has in their question.  Also make sure your 'id' in the render method is set to the ID attribute of your contaning element.

Answer (score 2):

Use `#` instead of `?`

`?` is used to begin query strings and will mess with `method=GET` type responses.  `#` is the anchor symbol and will work.