# Warning logo if captcha is not submitted

Tags: php, html, css

I have a form that has a Google CAPTCHA v2 tick box. Basically, I want the form to not submit unless the captcha has been filled in. At the moment, if the form is filled in without the captcha, the form will `echo "<h1>You did not fill in the CAPTCHA<h1>";` which appears on a new page.

However, instead I want it to remain on the same page and raise a warning, preventing them from submitting so they dont lose what they wrote in the form.

SCRIPT TO CHECK CAPTCHA (PHP):

```
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
  $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
}
if(!$captcha){
    echo '<h1>You did not fill in the CAPTCHA<h1>';
    exit;
}
$secretKey = "my_secret_key";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// post request to server
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . urlencode($secretKey) .  '&response=' . urlencode($captcha);
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
// should return JSON with success as true
if($responseKeys["success"]) {
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "mail sent failed";
        
    }
    else {
        header('Location: ../inquire.php?success=true');
    }
    
} else {
    echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
    
}
```

CODE SCRIPT MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE:

```css
.contact1-form {
  width: 390px;
}

.contact1-form-title {
  display: block;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #333333;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 44px;
}

input.input1 {
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

input.input1+.shadow-input1 {
  border-radius: 25px;
}

textarea.input1 {
  min-height: 150px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

textarea.input1+.shadow-input1 {
  border-radius: 25px;
}


/*---------------------------------------------*/

.wrap-input1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.input1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #e6e6e6;
  font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #666666;
}

.shadow-input1 {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: rgba(87, 184, 70, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer></script>
</head>

<body>

  <form action="service.php" method="post" role="form" class="contact1-form validate-form">
    <span class="contact1-form-title">
          Apply for our service
        </span>
    <?php
            if($_GET['success']){
                echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Thank you for contacting us.</div>';
            }
        ?>
      <div class="wrap-input1 validate-input" data-validate="Full name is required">
        <input class="input1" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full name">
        <span class="shadow-input1"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="wrap-input1 validate-input" data-validate="Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
        <input class="input1" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="shadow-input1"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="wrap-input1 validate-input" data-validate="Social media handles are required: @johnsmith">
        <input class="input1" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Social media handles">
        <span class="shadow-input1"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="wrap-input1 validate-input" data-validate="Message is required">
        <textarea class="input1" name="message" placeholder="Tell us about yourself"></textarea>
        <span class="shadow-input1"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_site_key"></div>
      <br>

      <div class="container-contact1-form-btn">
        <button class="contact1-form-btn" type="submit">
            <span>
              Send Email
              <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
          </button>
      </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: You will have to validate captcha using jQuery Ajax, as in (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408575/google-recaptcha-validate-using-jquery-ajax#:~:text=ajax(%7B%20type%3A%20%22POST%22,function(response)%20%7B%20console.)

Comment: If its not too much trouble, can you post an answer that i can implement to my code script? @PaulBaiju

Comment: okey, i have answered it, Check if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <form method="post" role="form" class="contact1-form validate-form" id="loginForm">
    <span class="contact1-form-title">
          Apply for our service
        </span>

      <div class="wrap-input1 validate-input" data-validate="Full name is required">
        <input class="input1" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full name">
        <span class="shadow-input1"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="wrap-input1 validate-input" data-validate="Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
        <input class="input1" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="shadow-input1"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="wrap-input1 validate-input" data-validate="Social media handles are required: @johnsmith">
        <input class="input1" type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Social media handles">
        <span class="shadow-input1"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="wrap-input1 validate-input" data-validate="Message is required">
        <textarea class="input1" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Tell us about yourself"></textarea>
        <span class="shadow-input1"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_site_key"></div>
      <br>

      <div class="container-contact1-form-btn">
        <button class="contact1-form-btn" type="submit">
            <span>
              Send Email
              <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
          </button>
      </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        $secretKey = "my_secret_key";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        // post request to server
        $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . urlencode($secretKey) .  '&response=' . urlencode($captcha);
        $response = file_get_contents($url);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        // should return JSON with success as true
        if($responseKeys["success"]) {
            if(!$mail->Send()) {
                echo "mail sent failed";
                
            }
            else {
                header('Location: ../inquire.php?success=true');
            }
            
        } else {
            echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
            
        }
    }else{
     echo '<h1>You did not fill in the CAPTCHA<h1>';
    }

}else{
   //Nothing
}
?>
```

JS

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var loginForm = $("#loginForm");
  //We set our own custom submit function
  loginForm.on("submit", function(e) {
    //Prevent the default behavior of a form
    e.preventDefault();
    //Get the values from the form
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var subject = $("#subject").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    //Our AJAX POST
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "service.php",
      data: {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        subject: subject,
        message: message,
        //This will tell the form if user is captcha varified.
        gresponse: grecaptcha.getResponse()
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        //console.log("Form successfully submited");
      }
    })
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this. I changed the PHP for your script and then changed the HTML for your script. I then added the JS to head in the main file with the HTML (inquire.php). However, this did not do anything. When I tried using the form, I tried with CAPTCHA completed and it did not send the email, and when I tried without the CAPTCHA, it redirected back to the page and nothing happened. @PaulBaiju

Comment: No, simply if I fill in the CAPTCHA, it redirects to https://mywebsite.com/inquire.php?success=true and does not send an email. However, if I do not fill in the captcha, it redirects to https://mywebsite.com/inquire.php and does nothing

Comment: @slkdanfalvsd If you fill CAPTCHA, its supposed to redirect to `mywebsite.com/inquire.php?success=true`. right?? The sending email part was not mentioned in the question nor the code for it was given.