# Automatically send a form when google recaptcha V2 is completed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, recaptcha

i have installed google recaptcha V2 on my site, and i want automatically submit a form (WITHOUT PRESS ANY BUTTON) when google recaptcha is completed, here is my code...

```
$secretKey='HIDDEN';
$responseKey=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$IP=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey&remoteip=$IP";
$response=file_get_contents($url);
$response=json_decode($response);
    if($response->success){
         ....execute some php
    }
```

And here is my form....

```
<form action="" method="post" class="Form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="g-recaptcha"  data-sitekey="HIDDEN"></div>
</form>
```

Thanks for read, have a nice day!

Comment: Use a timer and keep pinging the server to see if captcha is verified or not. If verified just submit the form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReCaptcha: How to autosubmit the form when the captcha was send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342949/recaptcha-how-to-autosubmit-the-form-when-the-captcha-was-send)

Answer (score 0):

add a callback like this

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your-key-here" data-callback="submitForm" ></div>
```

Then include something like this in your javascript code

```
<script>
var submitForm = function () {
    $("#formID-goes-here").submit();
}
</script>
```